# Database.getQueryLocator return wrong data

Tags: salesforce

I am very puzzled on the result returned by the Database.getQueryLocator().

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    string query = 'Select Label, Batch_Name__c, SObject_Name__c, External_system__c from Batch_Upload_Config__mdt where Is_Active__c = true';
    System.debug(query);
    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

In the Query Editor, I entered the exact query and did get the correct data back. However when running the batch, instead of returning the records with 'Is_Active__c = true', it returns the records with 'Is_Active__c = false'.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is related to query on custom metadata types. When I changed to use custom object, I was able to get the correct result using Database.getQueryLocator().